# about unix time timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I have made a form with a datepicker and all is fine with the actual form and everything gets sent and saved on the database (MySQL).

My question is that is `$unix_time` a set format? I mean will a unix_time always be saved at the same time zone or is it just set to what ever the user puts in.

Here is a example to make it easier to explain what I mean.

I live in the UK and I post the form at `2014-02-05 09:59:00` and it is saved to the database as `2014-02-05 09:59:00`.

Someone else posts the form at exactly the same time and they live in America. The time they post it is `2014-02-05 04:59:00` what is 5 hours behind my UK time.

will there time get posted as `2014-02-05 09:59:00` or `2014-02-05 04:59:00` to the database.

here is my code to one of the $unix_time

```
$reg_start = $_POST['reg_start'];
$unix_time = strtotime($reg_start);
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unix_time);
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

its depend on mysql server time zone

for example Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is standard time zone

and any operation in mysql server synce with this time

Answer (score 1):

$unix_timeIt will not unified to the one timezone unless you will ask a user to set a timezone.
If you have time and timezone you must switch to [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pl/datetime.construct.php) object

```
$reg_start = $_POST['reg_start'];
$unix_time = strtotime($reg_start);

$reg_timezone = $_POST['reg_timezone'];

$date1 = new DateTime($unix_time, new DateTimeZone($reg_timezone));
```

Then your dates will look like this:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00+12:00
2000-01-01 01:45:00+13:45
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a field in your table that gives you current timestamp.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

From the doc :

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am reading it now just another question tho `The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store. If you store a TIMESTAMP value and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for conversion in both directions` does that mean that if someone posts the time from USA that the person in the UK will not see the correct time as the time zone has changed.